# Specify what classes I want my handler to run

Tags: android

I have a class with a handler in it and it works fine, but it then hits a class where I want the handler to stop if the timer has not already timed out. So if the handler reaches the end it should go to the Drunk class, if the user reaches the end of the app before the handler goes off, the handler should not go off. I have it going off at the end of the app but I don't want it too. It should stop once it hits the end of the app.

THANKS!

```
Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            toDrunk();
        }
    },20000);

public void toDrunk(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Drunk.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove that message from the handler when the activity is stopped. You can do that either by storing the runnable in some variable and then removing it using [`removeCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) or by [posting the runnable with some token](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long)) and then removing all messages with that token using [`removeCallbacksAndMessages`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)).